# Header should leak out the bootstrap container

Tags: css

I need to create a header that should exist inside a container (stylized with bootstrap 4+), but in my case, the header should leak out of the container on the right side, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I do not know if my logic is correct, but since the menu and content items should be inside a container (which has 1170px on a 1920px screen), probably the header should be, or not?

Even because if you look at the header, It has an icon that should stay inside the container. In that case what would come out is only the background, since out of the container nothing would exists.

```css
html,
body {
  background: #afaf71;
}

.myHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 71px;
}

.container-header {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: red;
  height: 71px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 71px;
}
```

```html
<header class="myHeader">
  <div class="container container-header">
    <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180828/sxw/kisspng-clip-art-computer-icons-user-download-chamber-of-d-talonpaw-svg-png-icon-free-download-175238-on-5b84c95a116717.2809616615354289540713.jpg" width="22" />
  </div>
</header>
```

This is my test code: https://jsfiddle.net/sy86vtcp/3/

How I can I solve this? If my logic is wrong, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I can't understand from your code what you were trying to do, as it only contains the header. Regarding wether it should be contained inside the body's wrapper - it's your choice

Comment: Hi @GalAbra, in my case I only trying to do the header inside my image, If you take a look, the header is inside a container (styled by bootstrap), but on the right side the red background escape, and go to right side on screen edge

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap why not have the header be a .row and then the menu + content be col-sm-4 and col-md-8 respectively?

```html
<div class="header row"> Header </div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-4">Menu</div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-8">Content</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND**

Im my case I just create a div called `container-hidden-color`, that has `position:absolute`, same background of my `html` and `body` tags, and `z-index:1`.

My header called `myHeader` has now background red (the same background from my container), and finally my container called `container-header`, has `z-index:2` and `background:red`.

Take a look at my code: https://jsfiddle.net/1jxc4zbu/

Now my header is "inside" the container but on the right side my header escape and go to the right edge of the screen (like in my example).